# Correct Method for setting/using a NULL value in PHP 'Greater than or equal' IF ELSE

Tags: php, if-statement, null

i have a simple if else statement and wondered if theres a better way of writing the code than I have listed below, the $price_data and $api_price are normally set but in some cases could be null / empty values, so if there is a empty value I need to revert back to $old_price

```
// now double the price compare api price and current price use highest value

if ($price_data >= $api_price) {
$price_double = $price_data; 
// If we encounter a null or empty value for $price_data use old price data
  if ($price_double == null){ 
      $price_double = $old_price; 
  }
} else {
$price_double = $api_price;  
// If we encounter a null or empty value for $price_data use old price data
  if ($price_double == null){ 
      $price_double = $old_price; 
  }   
}

$useprice = ($price_double * 2);
```

Comment: how would that ever work? $price_double would only become null if $price_data is, and a null value cannot be "greater than/equal to" to a number.

Comment: $price_data can either be a set price or a null value, I have a script that extracts price data from a website and the value of $price_data can sometimes be a empty/null value

Comment: so how would `(null >= $api_price)` ever succeed, unless api_price as null as well?

Comment: $api_price can also be a null or empty value, that issue of both $price_data and $api_price being null or empty then I need to revert back to a stored old price, but if there is a problem of say one of these values being not null either set as a space character or so forth than I run into problems with my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will do what you want:

```
if ((floatval($price_data) === 0) || (floatval($api_price) === 0)):
    $price_double = $old_price;
else:
    $price_double = ($price_data >= $api_price)?$price_data:$api_price;
endif;
```

Comment: Revised to take null/zero/empty values into account instead of JUST nulls.